# how to set priority in priority queue

Tags: java

I was learning Java and trying to learn priority queue in collections. I tried with below example from one website:

```
import java.util.*;    
class S
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PriorityQueue<String> queue=new PriorityQueue<String>();
        queue.add("Amit");
        queue.add("Vijay");
        queue.add("Karan");
        queue.add("Rahul");
        queue.add("Jai");

        System.out.println("iterating the queue elements:");
        Iterator<String> itr=queue.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

here results came is below:

```
Amit
Jai
Karan
Vijay
Rahul`
```

I was expecting the result as :

```
Amit
Vijay
Karan
Rahul
Jai
```

I am not able to understand how the result changes from my expectation and what type of normal or default priority is used.
In case i want to get the same result as per my expectation, what should i do using prioiryqueue?

Please help me.

Here i want the exact cause of default ordering in priority queue.

Comment: You need to use comparator to sort your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting javadoc of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue **in any particular order**.

As you can see, the ordering of the `PriorityQueue` doesn't matter when using `iterator()`. Now if you began to take values from the queue using `poll()`, you would get the values in lexicographical order, i.e. the *natural order* of `String`.

If you want a queue that returns items in insertion order, use a regular `Queue` implementation like `LinkedList` or `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: Just one more thing..as per my question, i checked with Debug in eclipse and queue is showing the same element order what iterator is showing. I also tried to understand the lexicographic but still doesn't able to understand how this was inserted for default ordering.

Comment: @SumitKumarAgarwal For `PriorityQueue`, the *ordering* (default or otherwise) applies to `poll()` and `remove()`, not to `iterator()`. Eclipse uses `toString()` for the display and that internally uses `iterator()`. Eclipse also shows the backing array named `queue`, which is a flat representation of a balanced binary tree, which also explains the weird iteration order.